# Volumes and surface areas for the $d-$sphere $S^d$ rather than the $d-$ball.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, spheres

I've been struggling with the concept of volume and surface area for the $d-$sphere $S^d$. For concreteness, I can give the $d-$sphere of radius $R$ an extrinsic definition by embedding it in $(d+1)-$dimensional Euclidean space:

$$S^d = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}: |x|=R\}$$

(although I can't see how one defines this intrinsically, any suggestions?)

$S^d$ is a d-dimensional manifold without boundary.

My confusion begins from here:

- Does it make sense to talk about the volume of $S^d$ given that it's merely a spherical shell and isn't "solid" in the conventional sense? Presumably, it's volume should be zero when viewed as an embedding in $R^{d+1}$? Note: I stress, I'm *not* asking for the volume of the region in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ enclosed by this spherical surface, but rather the volume of the shell $S^d$ itself. *What is the precise definition for the volume of a manifold without boundary?*
- *Does it make sense to speak of a surface area of $S^d$ given that it has no boundary itself? What is the precise definition for the surface area of a manifold without boundary?*

Note, I can see both concepts being totally clear for the $(d+1)-$*ball* because:

- The $(d+1)-$ball is "solid" in $(d+1)-$dimensional space and has a boundary $S^d$, so the concept of volume is intuitively clear to me here.
- The surface area of the $(d+1)-$ball is equally easy to visualise given that it possesses a boundary, and one would get the usual "surface area of a sphere". But, surely, the surface area of $B^{d+1}$ and the surface area of $S^{d}$ cannot be defined in the same way, whilst also giving the same answer?

I just can't make sense of this question when I consider $S^d$ as a manifold in it's own right, rather than through embedding. For instance, the volume of the closed unit disk $B^2$ in two dimensions is clearly $V(B^2)=\pi R^2$, and the surface area is corresponding the circumference of the boundary $S^1$: $A(B^2) = 2\pi R$.

My question is, what are $V(S^1)$ and $A(S^1)$ exactly? Is $V(S^1) = A(B^2)$? If there are issues with the small dimensionality here, one can ask the same question for $B^3$ and $S^2$.

I appreciate that this question is very muddled, so please fire away for any clarifications. It has very been painful to search the internet for answers to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue comes from the meaning of the words 'volume' and 'area'. In every day life volume is 3-dimensional and area is 2-dimensional and you never need to go higher than that so there is no confusion.

If you have a d-dimensional manifold, the natural thing to consider is its d-dimensional measure, this is usually called the volume for any d but if there is more than one manifold around you have to be careful which dimension of measure you mean. The d-dimensional sphere can be defined through an embedding in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ but you could also define it abstractly through charts which are all maps to $\mathbb{R}^d$ without ever mentioning $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$. The d+1-volume of the d-sphere is zero but the d-volume is not.

Similarly the word surface or area is often used for the d-1-dimensional measure of the boundary of a d-dimensional manifold. So you can consider the d-dimensional unit ball, its boundary is the d-1-dimensional sphere and the area of the boundary of the ball is the volume of the d-1-dimensional sphere.

**Edit**: I would say talking of the surface of a d-dimensional manifold without boundary is missleading and ideally shouldn't be used. The d-sphere has a (d-dimensional) volume but it has no boundary so at most you could say the area of its boundary is zero.

Comment: This clarifies things a bit! So $V(S^{d-1}) = A(B^d)$? Where $V$ is understood to relate to the $(d-1)$-dimensional volume measure for the $(d-1)-$sphere, and similarly $A$ is related to the $(d-1)$-dimensional volume measure for the $d-$ball?

Comment: Is it correct to say that the 3-volume of the 3-sphere is $4\pi R^2$?

Comment: @TheoreticalConfusion The 3-sphere is 3-dimensional, so the formula should have an $R^3$ at the end. Looking at wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere the constant term is $2\pi^2$ so the volume is $2\pi^2R^3$.

Comment: You are, of course, absolutely right. The 2-volume of the 2-sphere is $4\pi R^2$. Many thanks!

Comment: @quarague Quick clarification re. final paragraph: you say that surface area refers to the $(d-1)- $dimensional measure of the boundary of a $d-$manifold. $S^d$ has no boundary, so does this mean we can't ascribe a genuine surface area to $S^d$? Your post appears to define the surface area of the $d-$ball (and therefore the volume of $S^{d-1}$) rather than the surface area of $S^d$.